# Text in a div wont fit

Tags: html, css, image

So im making a "Meet The Team" page but the text does not want to fit inside the div. I know im doing something wrong so any help would be appreciated 

This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" 
 name="viewport"><!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Login</title>
 </head>
<body>
<header><a href="homepage.html"><p id="college">Homepage</p></a></header>
    <div><img class="top-logo" src="images/logo.png"></div>

    <div class="laura1"><img class="laura" src="images/laura.jpg"><p>Laura - L2 Coordinator graphic designer and dance enthusiast. </p></div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js">
</script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

and this is the CSS

```
.laura1 {
width: 75%;
height: 150px;
background-color: white;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
.laura {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: auto;
}
#text1 {
font-size: 12.5px;
padding-left: 140px;
color: black;
}
```

Oh and this is what it turns out like with the code https://gyazo.com/b152d83601a127eeb3d758e85f26fca6

Comment: What do you want as an end result. Do you have a mockup?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a8ff2b4d4594c6f3ee1aa82a62b5acbf

Comment: Can you add more of your code. You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: Added in the full page of code to help out more

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try... I have used flexbox to align the text. You can change background colours to get the desired results.

```
.laura1 {
width: 25%;
padding: 15px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.laura {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
#text1 {
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
color: black;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYPmBW

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flex-box` positioning on parent class.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/swordys/ngLg7tmL

Comment: This worked with a few adjustments on the height! Tysm